# Titanic dataset visualization query

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, data-analysis

if I want to plot 'bar-graph' having 'Embarked' column on x-axis and number of death-counts on y-axis. How should I do this ?

sns.barplot(x = 'Embarked', y = titanic['Survival'].value_counts(), data = titanic)

my dataframe name is 'titanic'.
'Survival' column has 'dead' and 'alive' values.

but it is giving me empty plot. How should I write the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
sns.countplot(x="Embarked", hue="Survival", data=titanic)
plt.show()
```